# Caracteres especiais WebService C# SQL X Base Firebird

Tags: c#, delphi, web-service, asmx, firebird-2.5

Tenho uma integração feita por `Web-service (asmx) , C# e SQL Server`.
Esse Web-Service é consumido por um software de terceiros que usar Delphi e Firebird.

O problema é que ao integrar um campo string que tenha caracteres especiais, estão aparecendo interrogações (??) no lugar dos caracteres.

> Por exemplo, o programa Delphi envia um cadastro de cliente com o nome
>   João , quando chega no web-service está Jo??o.

Existe algo que eu possa fazer no web-service para evitar esse problema? ou o tratamento deve ser feito do lado do client? E o que deveria ser feito?

Tentei incluir um globalization para resolver a situação, não deu certo:

```
<globalization
 requestEncoding="iso-8859-1"
 responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"
 responseHeaderEncoding="iso-8859-1"
 fileEncoding="iso-8859-1"
 resourceProviderFactoryType=""
 enableBestFitResponseEncoding="true"/>
```

Exemplo do WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    public MessageRet IntegrarItemInsumo(ItemInsumo Object)
    {
        try
        {
            return Object.Add();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual o charset do web-service? poste como você esta recebendo os dados e o método que recebe ele.

Comment: Estava com UFT-8 , após ler alguns post eu inclui o globalization no config, mas não adiantou.                                                        <globalization
        requestEncoding="iso-8859-1"
        responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"
        responseHeaderEncoding="iso-8859-1"
        fileEncoding="iso-8859-1"
        resourceProviderFactoryType=""
        enableBestFitResponseEncoding="true"/>

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e poste como você faz quando recebe os dados.

Comment: user3410955, acredito que o seu cliente não esteja informando o `ContentType` apropriado, tente forçar o `HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentType` para `text/xml; charset=UTF-8` antes de ocorrer a deserialiação.

Comment: @TobyMosque , quando você diz cliente seria do lado do software Delphi e não do webservice C# ?

Comment: @BrianSouza, sim, cliente é a aplicação Delphi que consome o seu WebService, porém você pode tentar alterar este cabeçalho na sua aplicação.

Comment: @TobyMosque , como ? teria algum link para me instruir ?

Answer (score 1):

Brian, acredito que o Cliente escrito em Delphi que consome o seu WebService está enviando o `ContentType` incorreto, neste caso você pode entrar em contato com o seu cliente e pedir para que utilize o `text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1`.

Ou você pode fazer um `arranjo técnico provisório` e modificar o `ContentType` de todos os requests no seu `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1";
}
```

caso também não funcione com `iso-8859-1`, tente o `UTF-8`